# MySQL get difference between max and min values for select rows

Tags: mysql, max, min

I want a query that gets the difference between the max and min values grouped by day.  My attempt does not work:

```
SELECT date(`date`), 
   (max(value) - min(value)) as value,
FROM `sub_meter_data` 
where date(sub_meter_data.date) > '2012-10-01' 
  and sub_meterID in('58984','58985','58986','58987')
group by date(`date`);
```

Each sub_meter has a value that might be >3000, but only differs by < 10 per day.  I want the difference, ie a result <10.  With the query above I get results >3000.

This query below, just selects one meter, and give the correct results, the max (17531), the min (17523), and the difference (8).

```
SELECT date(sub_meter_data.date) as date,
   max(value) as max_meter,
   min(value) as min_meter, 
   max(value) - min(value) as diff,
FROM `sub_meter_data`
where date(sub_meter_data.date) > '2012-10-01' 
  and sub_meterID in('57636')
  group by date(sub_meter_data.date)
```

But adding another meter into the in clause, give a bad result, the max is 17531, and the min is 3021, the diff is 14510.  But I want the diff for each meter, then summed together.

```
SELECT date(sub_meter_data.date) as date,
   max(value) as max_meter,
   min(value) as min_meter, 
   max(value) - min(value) as diff,
   FROM `sub_meter_data`
where date(sub_meter_data.date) > '2012-10-01' 
  and sub_meterID in('57636', '57628')
  group by date(sub_meter_data.date)
```

Another attempt I've tried is:

```
SELECT date(sub_meter_data.date) as date,
   sum(CASE WHEN sub_meterID = '57628' OR sub_meterID = '57636' THEN (max(value) -     min(value)) ELSE 0 END) as value
   FROM `sub_meter_data`
where date(sub_meter_data.date) > '2012-10-01'
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152781/sql-max-and-min-time-between-two-fields-changing?rq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072231/mysql-how-to-select-minium-and-maximum-in-one-union-query?rq=1

Comment: What is not working about your query? Error message, invalid data? Can you provide an example of the response?

Comment: I get a result but the number is way too high.  I'll detail the expected result above.

Comment: did you try putting max(val) - min(val) < 10  in the where clause?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The query is only grouping by day (date), but you want to group also by meter, so you need to add that into your `group by`:

```
select sub_meterID, date(`date`) as day, max(value) - min(value) as value
from `sub_meter_data`
where date(`date`) > '2012-10-01'
    and sub_meterID in ('58984','58985','58986','58987')
group by sub_meterID, date(`date`);
```

Then if you want to sum the differences by day you can do:

```
select day, sum(diff) as total_diff
from (
    select sub_meterID, date(`date`) as day, max(value) - min(value) as diff
    from `sub_meter_data`
    where date(`date`) > '2012-10-01'
       and sub_meterID in ('58984','58985','58986','58987')
    group by sub_meterID, date(`date`)
    ) a
group by day
```

Or if you want to sum by meter:

```
select sub_meterID, sum(diff) as total_diff
from (
    select sub_meterID, date(`date`) as day, max(value) - min(value) as diff
    from `sub_meter_data`
    where date(`date`) > '2012-10-01'
       and sub_meterID in ('58984','58985','58986','58987')
    group by sub_meterID, date(`date`)
    ) a
group by sub_meterID
```

Comment: Wow!  The "sum by meter" example you have given is spot on.  Thanks so much.  I have to study that query and understand it.  Thanks Xint0.